# Serialize MirageJS response to fit EF Core API type List<>

Tags: reactjs, frontend, ui-testing, miragejs

I am trying to mock my EF Core API using Mirage but cannot figure out how to serialize my output. The front end is expecting something like:

[{id:1, name:"name1", weight: 150}, {id:2, name:"name2", weight: 140}]

but Mirage is returning something like:

data: {[{id:1, name:"name1", weight: 150}, {id:2, name:"name2", weight: 140}]}

I can explicitly return just the hardcoded array in the route handler and it works, but I want to be able to use Factories, Models, and Serializers to achieve this. What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the root attribute to false in the serializer. By setting root to false, the result will not be rooted inside of an object. Note that I think embed must be set to true if you are going to do this as it is defaulted to false. The solution will look something like this:

```
createServer({
  serializers: {
    person: RestSerializer.extend({
      embed: true,
      root: false,
    }),
  },
  //... rest of createServer
})
```